# How to get value_counts for a spark row?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with 3 columns storing 3 different predictions. I want to know the count of each output value so as to pick the value that was obtained max number of times as the final output.

I can do this in pandas easily by calling my lambda function for each row to get value_counts as shown below. I have converted my spark df to pandas df here, but I need to be able to perform similar operation on the spark df directly.

```
r=[Row(run_1=1, run_2=2, run_3=1, name='test run', id=1)]
df1=spark.createDataFrame(r)
df1.show()
df2=df1.toPandas()
r=df2.iloc[0]
val_counts=r[['run_1','run_2','run_3']].value_counts()
print(val_counts)
top_val=val_counts.index[0] 
top_val_cnt=val_counts.values[0]
print('Majority output = %s, occured %s out of 3 times'%(top_val,top_val_cnt))
```

The output tells me that the value 1 occurred the most number of times- twice in this case -

```
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+
| id|    name|run_1|run_2|run_3|
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|test run|    1|    2|    1|
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+

1    2
2    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64

Majority output = 1, occured 2 out of 3 times
```

I am trying to write a udf function which can take each of the df1 rows and get the top_val and top_val_cnt. Is there a way to achieve this using spark df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python's code should be similar, maybe it will help you

```
  val df1 = Seq((1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2)).toDF()
  df1.show()
  df1.select(array('*)).map(s=>{
    val list = s.getList(0)
    (list.toString(),list.toArray.groupBy(i => i).mapValues(_.size).toList.toString())
  }).show(false)
```

output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|  2|
|  1|  2|  3|  3|
|  2|  2|  2|  2|
+---+---+---+---+

+------------+-------------------------+
|_1          |_2                       |
+------------+-------------------------+
|[1, 1, 1, 2]|List((2,1), (1,3))       |
|[1, 2, 3, 3]|List((2,1), (1,1), (3,2))|
|[2, 2, 2, 2]|List((2,4))              |
+------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @AndrzejS. I was looking for something like this only :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a test dataframe similar like yours.

```
 list = [(1,'test run',1,2,1),(2,'test run',3,2,3),(3,'test run',4,4,4)]
df=spark.createDataFrame(list, ['id', 'name','run_1','run_2','run_3'])

newdf = df.rdd.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[1],x[2:])) \
.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[1],x[2][0],x[2][1],x[2][2],[max(set(x[2]),key=x[2].count )])) \
.toDF(['id','test','run_1','run_2','run_3','most_frequent'])


>>> newdf.show()
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
| id|    test|run_1|run_2|run_3|most_frequent|
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
|  1|test run|    1|    2|    1|          [1]|
|  2|test run|    3|    2|    3|          [3]|
|  3|test run|    4|    4|    4|          [4]|
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
```

Or you need to handle a case when each item in list is different. i.e returning a null.

```
list = [(1,'test run',1,2,1),(2,'test run',3,2,3),(3,'test run',4,4,4),(4,'test run',1,2,3)]
df=spark.createDataFrame(list, ['id', 'name','run_1','run_2','run_3'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf
def most_frequent(*mylist): 
    counter = 1
    num = mylist[0] 

    for i in mylist: 
        curr_frequency = mylist.count(i) 
        if(curr_frequency> counter): 
            counter = curr_frequency 
            num = i 

            return num
    else:
            return None
```

Initializing counter to '1' and returning count if its greater than '1' only.

```
df.withColumn('most_frequent', most_frequent('run_1', 'run_2', 'run_3')).show()

+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
| id|    name|run_1|run_2|run_3|most_frequent|
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
|  1|test run|    1|    2|    1|            1|
|  2|test run|    3|    2|    3|            3|
|  3|test run|    4|    4|    4|            4|
|  4|test run|    1|    2|    3|         null|
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
+---+--------+-----+-----+-----+----+
```